# VBA How to "Lock" Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to lock the excel sheet from being altered by the user while my vba code runs and modifies the excel sheet?

Comment: I would be curious about HOW you could build a macro *allowing* user to modify worksheet data while a macro runs!

Comment: I was wondering the same thing as idevelop, are you waiting on timers or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your code is active then I'm not sure why the user has the ability to modify data at the same time - the macro hourglass should be displayed rendering interaction impossible

Can you pls post your code?

Options you may consider include

1. adding a progress bar to let users know something is happening (ie don't play while code is running), and how long there is to go
   This example from Walkenbach is useful
   http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/displaying_a_progress_indicator/
2. making the Excel Application invisible while the work is occurring

   ```
   Application.Visible = False
   'code
   Application.Visible = True
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Coming from Excel 2003 ... protecting a sheet without additional actions will prevent user entry **and** VBA manipulations. In order to prevent user interaction with locked cells but still allow VBA you may use the `UserInterfaceOnly` property. This can only be done via VBA, there is no way to "manually" protect a sheet in this way. If you manually unprotect a sheet this property is removed. Therefore it's a good idea to set this property on workbook/sheet open/activate events, e.g.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim SH As Worksheet
    ' allow some non-destructive activities
    For Each SH In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        SH.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, _
                        AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, _
                        AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
    Next SH
End Sub
```